# How to get $var outside the function without using global php?

Tags: php, function, global-variables

Need small help here. Was reading how bad it is to add global var within function and call it outside but having small issue getting the vars outside. Global helped but I want to be safe also since I am handling some files here

my loop is this

```
<?php 
require_once('functions.php'); 
?>

<?php 
foreach( $files as $key=> $file ){  

global $download_link;
get_file_info($key,$file);
?>

<span><a href="<?php echo $download_link ?>"><?php echo $file->name ?></a></span>

<?php } ?>
```

**PART** of my function.php  /  is about 150 lines long but this is main snipp

```
function  get_file_info($key,$file){

global $download_link;
$access     = explode(",",$file->access);
$permission = in_array(1,$access);

if($permission){

$download_link = 'ok to download';
}else{
$download_link = 'canot download';
}


}
```

beside the link var I also have few others like date , counter etc but they are all bound by some condition.

I tried to do

return $link; at the end of the function instead using global  but getting undefined variable error;

SO base question here is ,   how to   get the download_link var outside the function without using global ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a lot easier by modifying your File class

```
class File {

    # ...

    function get_url() {
        return in_array(1, explode(',', $this->access))
            ? $this->url  # return the file's url
            : "/path/to/subscribe" # return a default path for non-access
        ;
    }
}
```

Your HTML would use it as follows

```
<?php

foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo '<a href="'.$file->get_url().'">Download this '.$file->name.'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you just use `get_file_info` to set `$download_link`, why not just return `$permission` and define `$download_link` outside the function?

```
<?php 
function  get_file_info($key,$file){
    $access     = explode(",",$file->access);
    $permission = in_array(1,$access);
    return $permission;
}

foreach( $files as $key=> $file ){  
    $download_link = 'canot download';
    if(get_file_info($key,$file)) {
        download_link = 'ok to download';
    }
    echo '<span><a href="$download_link ">'. $file->name . '</a></span>';
} 
?>
```

Comment: like advised it is much more than just link var that I have in that function. Is about 150 lines long and everything works except the vars after conditions within the function

Comment: Okay, but can you make the function return `$permission` anyway? If so, my answer is still valid.

Comment: I had everything within conditions ,   trying to make clean files here and separate the outputs , so I rather put everything within the function . this is why I am trying to stay away from conditions with the loop file or should I say html output file

Comment: You say on the question that you tried to return `$link`, but got an error. That's because there's no `$link` variable, you can return `$download_link` instead. Also, you say you want to avoid globals to "stay safe". The problem with globals is not related to security, it's about namespace collision and code maintainability.

Comment: I was returning $download_link; did not comment correctly there and I get undefined var error, I am sure that all var names are correct

Answer (score 0):

You may change your loop like this:

```
    <?php 
require_once('functions.php'); 
?>

<?php 
foreach( $files as $key=> $file ){  

   $download_link = get_file_info($key,$file);

?>

<span><a href="<?php echo $download_link ?>"><?php echo $file->name ?></a></span>

<?php } ?>
```

And your function code:

```
  function  get_file_info($key,$file){
 $access     = explode(",",$file->access);
 $permission = in_array(1,$access);

  if($permission){

return  'ok to download';
  }
  else {
return 'canot download';
  }
 }
```